# script to find "deny" ACE in ACLs, and remove it

Tags: grep, find, acl

On my 100TB cluster, I need to find dirs and files that have a "deny" ACE within their ACL, then remove that ACE on each instance. I'm using the following:

```
# find .  -print0 | xargs -0 ls -led | grep deny -B4
```

and get this output (partial, for example only)

```
-r--rw----  1 chris     GroupOne           4096 Mar  6 18:12 ./directoryA/fileX.txt
 OWNER: user:chris
 GROUP: group:GroupOne
 0: user:chris allow file_gen_read,std_write_dac,file_write_attr 
 1: user:chris deny file_write,append,file_write_ext_attr,execute 
--
-r--rwxrwx  1 chris     GroupOne       14728221 Mar  6 18:12 ./directoryA/subdirA/fileZ.txt
 OWNER: user:chris
 GROUP: group:GroupOne
 0: user:chris allow file_gen_read,std_write_dac,file_write_attr 
 1: user:chris deny file_write,append,file_write_ext_attr,execute 
--
 OWNER: user:bob
 GROUP: group:GroupTwo
 0: user:bob allow dir_gen_read,dir_gen_write,dir_gen_execute,std_write_dac,delete_child,object_inherit,container_inherit 
 1: group:GroupTwo allow std_read_dac,std_write_dac,std_synchronize,dir_read_attr,dir_write_attr,object_inherit,container_inherit 
 2: group:GroupTwo deny list,add_file,add_subdir,dir_read_ext_attr,dir_write_ext_attr,traverse,delete_child,object_inherit,container_inherit 
--
```

As you can see, depending on where the "deny" ACE is, I can see/not-see the path. I could increase the `-B` value (I've seen up to 8 ACEs on a file) but then I would get more output to distill from...

What I need to do next is extract `$ACENUMBER` and `$PATHTOFILE` so that I can execute this command:

```
chmod -a# $ACENUMBER $PATHTOFILE
```

Additional issue is that the find command (above) gives a relative path, whereas I need the full path. I guess that would need to be edited somehow.

Any guidance on how to accomplish this?

Comment: If you select code blocks and then hit the `{}` button in the editor, it usually does the right thing and prepends four spaces before every line, asking for the code formatting.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that next time.

Comment: Are you interested specifically in the _current user_? The GNU `find(1)` utility will use `access(2)` if you use `-readable`, `-writable`, or `-executable`, to determine if these conditions are true, and `access(2)` will take ACLs into account. Or are you interested in `deny` rules that apply to any user or group?

Comment: Due to a bug and/or initial misconfiguration, I have a whole bunch of these weird "deny" ACLs that i need to delete, in order to grant everyone full access (can't do it now b/c of canonical ordering). Files could be made by any of 60+ users in 12 groups. Manually this is a 4 step process: get file from the error log (when a chmod gets run for everyone, it will skip files, exported this to a doc), do ls -led, chmod -a# , then chmod +a everyone. Repeat for next file. At last count I have over 700+ files

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question: To output absolute file paths make your argument a full path i.e.

```
      find /my/full/path -print0
```

Comment: yes, but I was hoping to cut down on volume of files to be examined for the sake of time. The portion i'm interested in is about 50-60% of the entire cluster. I suppose it doesn't matter when run overnight tho... Oh I see, qualify full to get full path... Me big dummy...

Comment: got this from support today: 'code' for x in $(find /mydirectory -mindepth 1); do if [ $(ls -led $x | grep deny | wc -l | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//') -gt 0 ]; then chmod -a# "$(ls -led $x | grep deny | cut -d ":" -f 1)" $x; fi; done

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in $(find /mydirectory -mindepth 1); do
    if [ $(ls -led $x | grep deny | wc -l | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//') -gt 0 ]; then
        chmod -a# "$(ls -led $x | grep deny | cut -d ":" -f 1)" $x;
    fi;
done
```